# Resource's businessHours is not working on weekends in agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

First of all, excuse me for my english, I'm from México.

My problem is this...

I have this code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    businessHours: false,   // to enable all 24 hours regardless of the businessHours per resource
    weekends: true,         // to allow navigation between weekend days
    resources: [
        { id:1, title: "Employe 1", businessHours: { start:"08:00:00", end:"12:00:00" } },
        { id:2, title: "Employe 2" }
    ]
});
```

As you can see, I'm using fullcalendar's schedule plugin in agendaDay mode (timeline slot in vertical), and what I do is declaring 2 resources, one with businessHours and other without businessHours. The problem here (I don't know if it's a bug) is in navigation in weekend days. When viewing no-weekend days no problem, but when weekend days are viewed the **resources timeline are disabled** as if these was without businessHours, BUT that happens only for resources with businessHours (those that don't have this property works fine), STILL when globally the businessHours property is set to false (as you can see in the initializacion). So, the problem is that, I need show resources with businessHours for each, because for my a resource is an employe and each one can has different schedule and can there are more that  one employe by day, and that's because I need manage a businessHour per-resource and not globally.
Some help please?

Regards!

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or equivalent.

Comment: The agendaDay view knows nothing about resources, it's part of standard fullCalendar and designed to work without resources, which are part of the extra Scheduler plugin. So I think it ignores your resource, and thus your businessHours for that resource. Perhaps if you set  groupByResource (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/groupByResource/) true, then it show a column per resource for that day, and will take the resource settings into consideration. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Void Ray I can't reproduce the issue in JSFiddle because it seems fullcalendar have not url of it's scheduler plugin as cdn or equivalent.

ADyson, this is a url using fullcalendar' scheduler plugin in agendaDay mode, although resources have not defined businessHours at level resource. And I used groupByResource with true value, but not working.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question before. This isn't really related to resources specifically. See my answer below, I think this will help you more than my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, by default, if you just give times for your business hours and don't set days of the week, then fullCalendar assumes that you meant only Monday to Friday.

The default business hours, if not specified at all, are Monday-Friday 09:00-17:00. It looks like by specifying your own hours, you overwrite only the times, but not the days.

The simple solution is to explicitly specify all the days of the week:

```
resources: [
    { id:1, title: "Employee 1", businessHours: { dow: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], start:"08:00:00", end:"12:00:00" } },
    { id:2, title: "Employee 2" }
]
```

The `dow` parameter takes an array of numbers signifying the days of the week o which to enable the business hours, where 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday etc. through to 6 = Saturday.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/ for more details.

Comment: Hi ADyson, I have found the solution already yesterday and is the same solution that you says, although I still thinking it´s a bug, because the businessHours was set to false globally , and it should works fine, but not.
Thanks! (:

Comment: It's true that businessHours was false globally, but you created a new businessHours object for that resource, so when you create that object it gives it the default days of the week values, because you didn't override them. It has to use some kind of value to decide what days to display it on. I think it's not unreasonable to expect that it could be using the default Mon-Fri, although the documentation could be clearer about it. Personally I don't think it's a bug, for that reason, but if you disagree you could still raise it with the fullCalendar people. Glad you fixed it anyway

Comment: @ADyson See this please :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468891/populating-linq-list-to-calendar-with-checkmarks-on-the-appropriate-dates